# Selenium WebDriver sendKeys does first partial match instead of full

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've got a not-quite-alphabetized list of states in a select input, each with a postal abbreviation as the value (NY, OK, etc.). My problem is that when I do a sendKeys line with, say, NY, my script selects Nebraska - the first item in the list starting with 'N'. How can I force it to do a full match?

```
return findByCss('div.modal-content md-select').sendKeys('NY');
```

Here's an example item:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="region in modal.regions" ng-value="region" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_13" aria-checked="true" value="AL" style="">
    <div class="md-text ng-binding">Alabama</div>
</md-option>
```

Comment: could you share the html code, if it's list you could create the object of `select` and call `selectByValue` function.

Comment: Put in an example item.

Comment: Can you link the page? Is the site expecting you to send 'NY' or 'New York'? The DIV in the above HTML has Alabama but the md-option has a value of 'AL'. Can you use the `value` attribute to filter the list instead?

Comment: This is not an html dropdown, so best best would be to send the whole state name. not sure why you don't want to do that.

Comment: If you're interested in handling a partial match, transform the partial match to a full state name internally and then select the correct option based on that.

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit vague but I hope this helps you.

```
    //First click the dropdown then do the following
            List<WebElement> yourListOfCities = driver.findElements(By.className("md-text ng-binding"));
//Loop through to find what you want
            for(int i =0; i<yourListOfCities.size();i++) {
         WebElement ele = yourListOfCities.get(i);
         String x = ele.getText();
         if(x.contains("Thing you want to find")){
             //Click the thing you want
             ele.click();

             System.out.println("Clicked the thing...");
```